# pyqt : resize qdockwidget in maya

Tags: python, resize, pyqt, maya, qdockwidget

[image: QDockWidget in standalone]
[image: QDockWidget in Maya]

I've made a tool for Maya. And I used QDockWidget within QMainWindow for entire UI composition. As you and I know, I can "saveState" and "restoreState" to retain QToolBar, QDockWidget, and so on.

I don't know the reason, but in Maya I can't "restoreState" the actual state. It can restore all of the state for QToolBar, QDockWidget except the size of QDockWidget. So I want to try to resize QDockWidget programmatically. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reimplementing the [sizeHint](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop) for the top-level content widget of the dock-widget:

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    _sizehint = None

    def setSizeHint(self, width, height):
        self._sizehint = QtCore.QSize(width, height)

    def sizeHint(self):
        if self._sizehint is not None:
            return self._sizehint
        return super(MyWidget, self).sizeHint()
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a simple demo that shows one way to implement this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class DockContents(QtGui.QWidget):
    _sizehint = None

    def setSizeHint(self, width, height):
        self._sizehint = QtCore.QSize(width, height)

    def sizeHint(self):
        print('sizeHint:', self._sizehint)
        if self._sizehint is not None:
            return self._sizehint
        return super(MyWidget, self).sizeHint()

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setCentralWidget(QtGui.QTextEdit(self))

        self.dock = QtGui.QDockWidget('Tool Widget', self)
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.dock)

        contents = DockContents(self)
        contents.setSizeHint(400, 100)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(contents)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.toolwidget = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.toolwidget)

        self.dock.setWidget(contents)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 600, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. You mean that I have to try reimplement **THE CONTENT WIDGET** of QDockWidget?

Comment: @Hyun-geunKim. Yes - the widget that is passed to `dockwidget.setWidget()`. Or you could just create a simple wrapper widget as in my answer and make it the parent of your current content widget.

Comment: I tried. But, nothing calls sizeHint of reimplemented widget... :(

Comment: @Hyun-geunKim. I added a demo script to my answer that works as intended. Hopefully you can adapt it to suit your needs.

Comment: Yes! It works. As you added, I used it as just Widget of QDockWidget.

Comment: Note: Always make sure, that your resize-calls through setSizeHint are made BEFORE you (might) call show() on the dockwidget. This trick will only work BEFORE show() is called and has no effect after it is called.