# Is there an event that fires when widget is shown and causes window size change?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a QMainWindow that, sometimes, resizes when I add a dock widget to it. I would like to prevent that size change because it makes the window too big for the screen.

I have thought to undock the widget if it causes the problem, but I don't find any QWidget event that trigger just after the window' size change. Is there any event that I could use in my dock widget to know that the window just resized because of it?

Comment: can't you set the max size of the window instead?

Comment: I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9862147) before, it worked quite well.

Comment: Thanks for your tips but in order to correctly see the other widgets, I would like to undock my docked widget. I thus need to find an event that fires after the window' size change.

Comment: "I don't find any QWidget event that trigger just after the window' size change". Doesn't the [resizeEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resizeEvent) what you need?

Comment: Do you mean overriding the QMainWindow::resizeEvent to emit a signal and connect to this signal in my dock widget implementation so I can verify the size of the window in it? If so, I may resize the window in my dock widget to ensure it is not too big for the screen, so it may retrigger the resizeEvent. I think it could cause endless loop :/